# How to connect accdb using UcanAccess to Android App?

Tags: android, ms-access-2010, ucanaccess

Finally, I was able to connect to sdcard, but now I want to connect to a DB in a shared folder on the network. I'm not getting. I have tried several ways and below follows my code case. Every help is welcome.

public class ConnectionClass {

```
public static Connection conn = null;

public Connection CONN(){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    String DRIVER = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
    String DbDsn = "jdbc:ucanaccess://";
    String DbServer = "//192.168.15.4";
    String DbPath = "/Banco";
    String DbName = "/DBase.accdb";

    String ConnUrl= DbDsn + DbServer + DbPath + DbName;

    try{
        String caminho_2 = DbServer+DbPath+DbName;
        System.out.println("Caminho - " + caminho_2);

        File teste = new File(caminho_2);
        if(teste.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Arquivo OK");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Não OK");
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Verificação Driver");
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {

            System.out.println("Problem in loading or "
                    + "registering MS Access JDBC driver");
            cnfex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Classificando Driver");

        System.out.println("String de conexão - " + ConnUrl);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnUrl);

        System.out.println("Conexão Estabelecida");

    }catch (SQLException cnfe){
        System.out.println(cnfe);
        System.out.println("Erro - 1");
    }catch (Exception se){
        System.out.println(se);
        System.out.println("Erro - 2");
    }
    return conn;
}
```

}

Comment: Look into implementing a web service & REST API on top of your existing Java service. It can then be used by any HTTP interaction (not limited to Android)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify where the Access database will actually be located. Will it be on the same device where your app will be running, or will it be in a remote location?